# User Picking from a list of cool unicode text like  in Python

Tags: python, unicode, user-input, fuzzywuzzy

So I have a list of names like: `["name", "", "foo"]` with 100 to 5000 elements and I want the user to type `foo` and the program getting `["", "foo"]` from which the user would pick one of

I've tried this:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
print(process.extract("hunni", ["", "some text"], limit=2))
```

which prints `[('', 0), ('some text', 0)]`

Any ideas? I might even use another language if it isn't possible in Python 3

Comment: I do not understand. You should never use unicode character for formatting (we have fonts for this). You may normalize the string (compatibility), before to use fuzzy. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize, 'NFKC'

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm just importing the list from somewhere else, not building it myself and doing it manually isn't possible because it'd be a different list every time. I've checked NFKC, seems to be enough, although not at all perfect, in my test it's converted about 75% correctly.

Comment: `[x for x in ["name", "", "foo"] if unicodedata.normalize( 'NFKC', x) == "foo"]` …

Comment: @JosefZ i dont get this, to make it clear `"", "foo"` have nothing to do with each other like the list is just random words including weird text like that